# why the compression ration is 0 using JSZip

Tags: javascript, xml, compression, jszip

I converted my downloadable xml file to zip using the following code but the file size is sill same and the compression ratio shows 0%

```
    var xmlcontent = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Body>";
    xmlcontent += json2xml(data);
    xmlcontent += "</Body>";

    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file("test1.xml", xmlcontent);
    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
    .then(function (content) {

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(content);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "test.zip";
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    });
```

The reason of compression was to decrease the size of the file the client retrieves but apparently it had no effect on it. Kindly suggest a way to decrease the file size.

Comment: Thanks got it. it is now working perfectly. You can put it as answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default compression setting for file(s) is `STORE` (= no compression) - as stated in the [documentation](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html)

Change it to `DEFLATE` with the `options` parameter of `.generateAsync(options)`

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("test1.xml", xmlcontent);
zip.generateAsync({
        type: "blob",
        compression: "DEFLATE"
    })
    .then(function (content) {
            ...
    });
```